# PHP error - undefined index on subarray of response

Tags: php, json

So I'm trying to handle an api response but I can't seem to bypass this error.
And yes im aware that this is a semidupe but I just couldn't find a solution.

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "message-count": "1",
    "messages": [{
        "to": "123",
        "message-id": "1234",
        "status": "0",
        "remaining-balance": "1",
        "message-price": "0.03",
        "network": "21901"
    }]
}';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $json_decoded['messages']['status'];

?>
```

error im getting : `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: status -- at line 14`

hopefully some1 can answer and not delete it...

Comment: Well, it's mostly because `$json_decoded['messages']['status']` does not exist. Try dumping the `$json_decoded` to see if your array keys exist. If they are, please post here a JSON dump example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your JSON indicates `messages` is an Array (declared using square brackets `[]`), meaning you'll have to tell it which element of the array you want to grab the status from:

```
echo $json_decoded['messages'][0]['status'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about array! Firstly you have to denote array's index then set array's value. So your code is wrong.

Correct last line like this:

```
$json_decoded['messages'][0]['status']
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Zed. Yes, like others said. `message` is an array. Check out this `print_r` of `$json_decoded`:

[image]

Check this working fiddle here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3188db556f9b743ffbc9ad138253a5901d2c48c3